# Sencha Touch: How does Ext.app.Application.launch() work?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've been working with Sencha Touch for a fair amount of time, and I created a bunch of applications, but I think I am still missing one of the key concepts in Sencha development:
I was wondering how does `Ext.app.Application.launch()` work to add to the viewport the views I create.

During launch() is it:

```
Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main');
```

equivalent to:

```
Ext.Viewport.add( Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main') );
```

If so, is this a feature implemented somehow in the application `launch()`, or does creating a `View` always adds it on top of the `Viewport`, regardless of being during `launch()`? I can't find any documentation about it, nor I could find the relevants piece of code in the sources.

Can someone explain how this works, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `MyApp.view.Main` have `fullscreen: true` set on it?  That config, per the docs, does:

> Force the component to take up 100% width and height available, by
>   adding it to Ext.Viewport.

From my understanding, `Ext.app.Application.launch()` is effectively just the same as `Ext.onReady`, but it's the recommended entry point for MVC applications.